# How to send WETH to a contract with the Buy Tokens method

Tags: transactions

I need to send WETH to the contract of sale using the buy Token method, it turns out only to send FTM, but I could not find how to send another coin to the contract using the desired method
[image]

```
Address = '0xb10Cae95449063D1C39f535258DCb2dc1dA1FcEb'

contract = web3.eth.contract(address=Address, abi=abi)

txn = contract.functions.buyTokens(sender_address, amountt).buildTransaction({
'from': sender_addres,
'value': web3.toWei(0.0000001,'ether'),
'gas': 250000,
'gasPrice': web3.toWei('200','gwei'),
'nonce': nonce,
})
```

Comment: That contract address doesnt exist on the mainnnet can you share the network you are using or the contract itself?

Comment: https://ftmscan.com/address/0xb10cae95449063d1c39f535258dcb2dc1da1fceb